# How can choose I python version in directly cmd?

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I have the next question. I have installed python3.9 and python3.10 on my Windows. Can I choose python version directly in work in cmd? Or I must do something else like to modify system environment variables list?

Thanks for answers!

Comment: If you regularly use multiple versions of Python, consider using the [Python Launcher for Windows.](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher)

Comment: Look into virtual environments which allow you to have Python version and dependencies per project.

Answer (score 0):

If you call in the cmd to py you will skip the most recent version, in your case Python 3.10, if you want the other version you have to call it as py -3.9 "name of the program".py, the same you can do with the first, do py -3.10 "name of the program".py